# Can't add TimePicker component from 'element-ui' library. How To add it correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**I need to add one component from 'element-ui' library to my project** (Laravel + Vue). I'm interested in `TimePicker`.

I added to my bootstrap.js file next code:

```
/**
 * Element, a Vue 2.0 based component library for developers, designers
 * and product managers.
 */
import { TimePicker } from 'element-ui'
import lang from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en'
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale'

// configure language
locale.use(lang)

// import components
Vue.component(TimePicker.name, TimePicker)
```

All this code was written according to the [docs](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart).

But I get error message in my browser:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register
>   the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
>   provide the "name" option.

I tried to import 'Button' component with the same set of code and it was working. But it doesn't work for TimePicker. 
**What I do wrong? Why It doesn't work**

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What is the value in `TimePicker.name`?

Comment: Try `Vue.use(TimePicker)`

Comment: @RoyJ Thank you for your reply. I found mistake. The name of the component that I was using in 'template' was wrong. I named it as ''time-picker" instead of "el-time-picker".

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my case, the name of the component that I was using in 'template' was wrong. I named it as "time-picker" instead of "el-time-picker"

**Don't forger to add prefix 'el-' to the name of your components when using them in your `<template>`-s.**

Full answer:

1)To add component globally to your app, add to your js file this code (the names of the components and other examples you can fined [here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart) ):

```
import { TimePicker } from 'element-ui'
import lang from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en'
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale'

// configure language
locale.use(lang)

// import components
Vue.component(TimePicker.name, TimePicker)
```

2. Add new component to your vue.js file, in `<templete>` section.:

   `<el-time-picker></el-time-picker>`